# How to make more than two fancy gradient stripes in tcolorbox?

Tags: environments, boxes, gradient

I use the following fancy `tcolorbox` definition:

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colframe=black!80,colback=black!10,sharpish corners,
skin=bicolor,interior style={left color=black!5,right color=black!35},segmentation style={left color=black!35,right color=black!5}}
```

Using `\tcblower` I can split the box, and make two fancy gradient stripe, but I would like to use more than two. How to do an environment with the same appearance, where I can use simple `\tcblower` or something like that to add another stripe?

Comment: Have you tried nested boxes from `tcolorbox` package? Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

maybe faking some broken boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    colframe=black!80,
    before=,
    after=\vskip-1pt,
    left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
    sharpish corners,
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}[skin=enhancedfirst,interior style={left color=black!35,right color=black!5}]
first
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[skin=enhancedmiddle,interior style={left color=black!5,right color=black!5,middle color=black!35}]
second
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[skin=enhancedmiddle,interior style={left color=black!35,right color=black!35,middle color=black!5}]
add as many as you want
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[skin=enhancedlast,interior style={left color=black!5,right color=black!35}]
last
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

this is documented in section 11.7 of the manual.

Comment: Yes, this is hacker solution :) Using single environment would be nicer!

Comment: @user3058699 As far as I know tcolorbox does not support more than one lower part, so you are either faking a single box (like I did) or using the overlay to draw the gradients over the box content (as @Harish did). If it is for the sake of a cleaner code, you could design a single command like `\myfakesinglebox{}{}{}{}` that embed the various environments (however you would still have three or more boxes in reality).

Comment: some kind of list or table solution is not possible inside a tcolorbox?

Answer (score 5):

With `tcolorbox 3.30 (2014/11/17)`, there are new possiblities to answer this question using the `raster` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,raster}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}% <- remove, if box should be not breakable

\newtcolorbox{xmybox}[1][]{      
  enhanced,colframe=black!80,size=tight,boxrule=0.5mm,
  lefttitle=3mm,righttitle=3mm,toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,
  clip upper,sharpish corners,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  breakable,pad at break*=0pt,% <- remove, if box should be not breakable
  #1
}

\newenvironment{mybox}[1][]{%
  \begin{xmybox}[#1]%
  \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1,raster row skip=0pt,
    enhanced,size=minimal,frame hidden,top=4pt,bottom=4pt,left=3mm,right=3mm,
    raster odd row/.style={interior style={left color=black!35,right color=black!5}},
    raster even row/.style={interior style={left color=black!5,right color=black!35}}]%
}{\end{tcbitemize}\end{xmybox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[title=Striped Box]
  \tcbitem first
  \tcbitem second
  \tcbitem \lipsum[3]
  \tcbitem another one
  \tcbitem yet another one
  \tcbitem last
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following is not breakable and the number of stripes can be customised with the `overlay` code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    enhanced jigsaw,
    boxrule=0pt,
    left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
    overlay={
          \path[preaction={left color=black!35,right color=black!5}]
               ($(frame.north west)!0.25!(frame.south west)$) rectangle
                     ($(frame.north east)!0!(frame.south east)$);
          \path[preaction={left color=black!5,right color=black!35}]
               ($(frame.north west)!0.5!(frame.south west)$) rectangle
                     ($(frame.north east)!0.25!(frame.south east)$);
          \path[preaction={left color=black!35,right color=black!5}]
               ($(frame.north west)!0.75!(frame.south west)$) rectangle
                     ($(frame.north east)!0.5!(frame.south east)$);
          \path[preaction={left color=black!5,right color=black!35}]
               ($(frame.north west)!1!(frame.south west)$) rectangle
                     ($(frame.north east)!0.75!(frame.south east)$);
          \draw[line width=1pt] (frame.south west) rectangle (frame.north east);
          }
}

\usepackage{lipsum}  %% just for demo
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If this needs to be breakable across pages, let me know.

Comment: It's important, that I would like to decide in the text where to start a new stripe. Typically at the end of a paragraph.